# Можно ли подружить Hilt с @Compose функциями?

Tags: kotlin

Можно ли подружить Hilt с @Compose функциями?

```
class DefaultScreen @Inject constructor(
    override val bottomScreen: @Composable () -> Unit

) : Screens


interface Screens {
    val bottomScreen: @Composable () -> Unit
}
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

> incompatible types: Function0 cannot be converted to Function2<?
> super Composer,? super Integer,Unit>
> return new DefaultScreen(bottomScreen)